# Magento customers shopping cart contents being seen by other customers

Tags: magento-1.7, varnish

I sometimes see shopping carts of others whilst navigating my site.

Some say that there is a bug that if one is logged in via admin you can see customer shopping carts if you then nivigate on the frontend.

Today one of my customers reported that when trying to checkout he saw some random product of high value (£250) appear in his cart after refreshing his browser.

I am running varnish cache. Persistent shopping cart is off.

Here are my varnish cache settings.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like Varnish is caching cart content. Did you holepunch the topcart and cart page?

Comment: how is your cache configured? varnish plugin? header or cart block in header excluded from cache? is your /checkout/ route excluded from cache?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I have added my varnish cache settings in admin to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before as well, when using Varnish. Somewhere last year I started working with [Nexcess Turpentine](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine) and they didn't have this issue (anymore). It took some tweaking to get it work properly, but the cart wasn't cached and other user specific stuff like the account pages are also holepunched by default.

Apart from that, this extension makes it possible to holepunch other URLs as well, as well as specific blocks, which can be configured within your own theme's layout.xml files.

So if you're experiencing an issue with Varnish, you might want to checkout this extension.